# Delphi 10 Seattle Android, after closing project can't compile

Tags: android, delphi

Does anyone have the same problem? I finish a project for Android and Close `Delphi`.  When I reopen, and select `Run`,  it starts compiling, linking, etc.

But the application is not working. There is only a black screen on the phone. When I make some mistakes in code it's compiling without any information about any error.

I have reinstalled Delphi, cleaned the project, and deleted project files and android manifest. Every time, it is the same.

Comment: Run the Android app in the debugger in delphi. See if the debugger complains. I've had similar cases where the android app would just randomly crash or behave oddly. Usually with a `Segment Fault` error.

Comment: Thank  you for your help, I discovered. In my case I must open saved project through welcome page -> open an existing project. Otherwise it will be not working properly. I believe, in my case, its seems for me like a bug or somthing similar. Thx for your time :-)